# Как переписать функцию-генератор внутри которой используется yield из forEach?

Tags: javascript, foreach, yield

Мне нужно получить функцию-генератор. Вот пример нерабочего кода:

```
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
const constants = require('./src/constants');

function* ArticleSummaries(page) {
    const $ = cheerio.load(page);
    $(constants.ARTICLE_SUMMARIES, constants.CONTEXT).each(function(elem) {
        yield({ url: $(this).attr('href'), name: $(this).text() });
    });
}
```

Как переписать код так, чтобы `ArticleSummaries` осталась функцией-генератор, но при этом проходя по каждому элементу сразу же `yield`-ить?

Пока нашел это [You can only yield in generators](http://2ality.com/2015/03/es6-generators.html#you-can-only-yield-in-generators) . В этой заметке сказано как переписать на for-конструкцию, но приведен слишком простой пример. У меня же по-сложнее и мне пока не удается переписать это с учетом моей ситуации с `cheerio`.

Мое представление о новом варианте с for-конструкцией такое(псевдокод):

```
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
const constants = require('./src/constants');

function* ArticleSummaries(page) {
    const $ = cheerio.load(page);
    for (let item of $(constants.ARTICLE_SUMMARIES, constants.CONTEXT)) {
        yield({ url: $(item).attr('href'), name: $(this).text() });
    });
}
```

Но мне пока не удается заставить этот вариант работать.

Comment: yield не получится использовать в forEach без сторонних библиотек. Используй обычный for цикл

Comment: @NikitaSmith Поправил формулировку своего вопроса. Прочтите еще раз